# R: Error when looping to replace synonyms on corpus

Tags: r, loops, corpus

I'm very new to R. Using the TM package, I'm trying to clean a set of txt documents by replacing synonyms. 
As I will be working with a lot of data, I have tried to set up a table using excel where the words in the first column will be replaced with the words in the second column, and perform a loop to replace the words in my corpus. My codes are as shown:

```
library(tm)

docs <- Corpus(DirSource("C:....txt files"))
list <- read.csv("C:\\.....synonyms list.csv", header=F)
for(s in 1:length(docs)){
  for(x in 1:nrow(list)){
    docs[[s]]$content <- gsub(list[x,1],list[x,2], docs[[s]])
  }
}
```

However, I got the error:`Error in [.data.frame(x$dmeta, tag) : undefined columns selected`

Does anyone knows what went wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: try to give a reproducible example, and avoid using `list` as a variable name. `list` is generally used to create a `list`, and you're using it to name a `data.frame`, that's confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of `docs[[s]]$content <- gsub(list[x,1],list[x,2], docs[[s]])` you need `docs[[s]]$content <- gsub(list[x,1],list[x,2], docs[[s]]$content)`. I say maybe because I cannot really test it without any data